# Two different physical ssd's for two different OS

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, bios

i have 1st SSD formatted as ext4 and installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it and i plan to get 2nd SSD and format it to NTFS and install Windows 8 on it.

Can i switch hard drives in a bios? e.g.:

```
if i want to boot with Ubuntu i will turn off the 2nd SSD
if i want to boot with Windows i will turn off the 1st SSD.
```

If it's possible i would buy the 2nd SSD and try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally yes, either through changing the boot order in bios, or by selecting a boot device in the system boot menu. If you don't want one bootloader stepping on the other, disconnect the other SSD and install.

You don't need to 'turn off' the SSD - the windows system can't see the linux FS without additional filesystem drives, if they exist, and the linux system generally can be told to not mount your windows bootloader.

Comment: Thanks. So it's possible to completely turn off SSD in a bios? I plan to turn off SSD with UBUNTU in bios and install clean SSD then install Windows on it. After i've done with games on windows i will turn off 2nd SSD.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. But not needed (though might come in handy during the windows installation).

Comment: I just unplugged mine, and left the side off while I set up the system, then plugged the drives back in. If you do it right, windows *shouldn't* overwrite or care about grub but better safe then sorry

Comment: You mean - you have unplugged yours when you was installing windows?

Comment: yup. it is a just in case thing but it worked

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to turn off the SSD's in BIOS. On the Ubuntu SSD, install the boot loader Grub (installed by default), and make sure it has entries for both Linux and Windows. Then set your boot device for the SSD containing Ubuntu.

This will make sure Grub gets started when you turn on your PC. After Grub starts at boot, you can choose to boot Windows or Ubuntu.

(in short, Grub also works for different disks, not just for different partitions)

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to mess with GRUB. Because i do gaming only on weekends (2 days in a row), so i won't have to choose what OS to load on every boot. I just want to turn off 2nd SSD then turn on 1st and able to work in ubuntu again/